# Convert String to Decimal Value Logstash Mutate

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have the following line:

```
012018121212XTED11      010FII TRXE CORCI           R$  000000000169000000000017450000000001690000000000172700000000017170000000001717000000000175000051000000000000002011000000000003474670000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRXTEDCTF006143\r
```

So i create a filter to extract the price:

```
grok {
        match => ["message", "(?<tipo_registro>.{2})(?<data_pregao>.{8})(?<codbdi>.{2})(?<codneg>.{12})(?<tpmerc>.{3})(?<nomres>.{12})(?<especi>.{10})(?<prazot>.{3})(?<modref>.{4})(?<preabe>.{13})(?<premax>.{13})(?<premin>.{13})(?<premed>.{13})(?<preult>.{13})(?<preofc>.{13})(?<preofv>.{13})"]
    }
```

The price is field **preabe**, but i need add a dot before two digits to convert to float, so this is my price in string :

```
00001650
```

I need add "." , so i will have

```
000016.50
```

Now convert to float and i will have

```
16.50
```

Any tips ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for ruby.  Here's some untested code:

```
filter {
   ruby {
      code => "event.set('preabe', event.get('preabe').to_i / 100)"
   }
}
```